# Self-made converter not working on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new at tkinter so don't judge me
I'm trying to do a converter that converts minutes into whatever else
but when I'm clicking on "Enter", nothing shows up, not even the sentence it's supposed to say in wrong input
Here's the code :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Minute converter")

initial = Label(root, text="How much minutes?")
initial.grid(row=0, column=0)

ini_ans = Entry(root, relief=SUNKEN, bd=3)
ini_ans.grid(row=1, column=0)


time_converter = Label(root, text="Do you want the answer in (S)econds, (H)ours or (D)ays? ")
time_converter.grid(row=3, column=0)

conv_ans = Entry(root, relief=SUNKEN, bd=3)
conv_ans.grid(row=4, column=0)

enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter", relief=SUNKEN, bd=3, command=lambda:add)
enter_button.grid(row=5, column=0)

answer = Entry(root, text="Answer goes here. Please do not touch.")
answer.grid(row=6, column=0)

def add():

    global seconds
    global hours
    global days

    seconds = 60
    hours = 60
    days = 1440

    ini_grp_lt = ini_ans.get
    conv_lt = conv_ans.get
    if conv_lt == "S":
        ini_ans.delete(0, END)
        conv_ans.delete(0, END)
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert(0, int(ini_grp_lt) / int(seconds))
    if conv_lt == "H":
        ini_ans.delete(0, END)
        conv_ans.delete(0, END)
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert(0, int(ini_grp_lt) * int(hours))
    if conv_lt == "D":
        ini_ans.delete(0, END)
        conv_ans.delete(0, END)
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert(0, int(ini_grp_lt) * int(days))
    else :
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert("I didn't understand.")

root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting it to put the waited value in the "answer" entry

Comment: you never called add -> `add()`

Comment: @AhmedAEK `add` is bound to `enter_button`

Comment: @JRiggles the lambda is bound to the button, the lambda doesn't call the add ...

Comment: Yes you're right, I just added "add()"  on the "command=lambda:add()" of the enter_button but i got an error :(  I'll resolve it by myself, thank you!

Comment: Just write `command=add`, no need for `lambda`

Comment: One problem is this: `conv_ans.get` is a function, `conv_ans.get()` will call the function and return the results. You're doing the former. The first step in debugging is to validate your assumptions. You're assuming `conv_lt` is a string when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's showing up because you've made a slight error in your command binding.

You could use:

```
enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter", relief=SUNKEN, bd=3, command=lambda: add())
```

*note the additional parentheses here...*

*OR* perhaps better - don't use a `lambda` at all:

```
enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter", relief=SUNKEN, bd=3, command=add)
```